# twitter api problem

Tags: php, twitter

i got one api after google search,

here is the link [send-tweets](http://twitapi.com/explore/direct_messages-new/)

How to use this api,

i should install any thing ,

what is the procedure for this api,

Comment: nice question, if there aren't dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this OAuth library: http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

```
$parameters = array('status' => date('Hi'));
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

That is the post to wall method in the Twitter OAuth library, you will need to authenticate with OAuth first, the code is provided in the examples section of the above download.

Comment: where i find the exact snippet,  but i have some of oauth snippet but that are not working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its using "curl".

[Twitter Dev](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries)

[Google Code Twitter API](http://code.google.com/p/php-twitter/)

here is the Twitter dev site with libraries. Under Google Code you can find a Twitter API class.